Firebase: How do I create user only after verifying condition?
How do I do the following?
if (something) {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => { .....
}

Since the code runs on the client, can't the user just change the code? How do I ensure a condition like, for example, I only allow gmail email accounts to sign up?

Realized I need blocking functions and to upgrade the account https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd

Not necessarily. You can make a call to the server, so the server verifies and then creates the account only on certain conditions. So the account doesn't need to be created from the client side. Take a look at option B on this answer.
